# Send a string id to server on POST method and get response

Tags: android, json, server, http-post

I am trying to send id to server on which a response will be generated against that id, my id against that server is OK but response is empty array of data.

```
try {
    httppost.setEntity(new StringEntity(vol_id));
    Log.e("vol", vol_id);

    HttpResponse resp = httpclient.execute(httppost);

    HttpEntity ent = resp.getEntity();

    getResult = EntityUtils.toString(ent);
    savePreferences("asset_data", getResult);
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: what kind of data are you sending back from the server  Json, String data etc ... It maybe easier to use the Google Volley library

Comment: Hi man, i suggest you use the Java net libary instead of the apache one because it has deprecated

Comment: i am sending string back to the server

Comment: cant we correct this code?

Comment: yeah but are you sending data back to the App or you just want to check for a success response??

Comment: i am sending data back to App .. and its a json

Answer (score 0):

```
Try this code with the concept and jar file of multipart entitiy to post string:

Make http request some like as you know:

    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://www.tumblr.com/api/write");

Then critical requirement is this to post string over id defined in server:

try {
    MultipartEntity entity = new MultipartEntity();

    entity.addPart("type", new StringBody("photo")); //photo is id for string defined to post
    httppost.setEntity(entity);
    HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
} catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
} catch (IOException e) {
}
```